# What does the Geomagnetic Field Sensor measure?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

[According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-mag), the Geomagnetic Field Sensor measures the Earth's magnetic field strength (in micro-Tesla, μT) along the x, y, and z axis. However, it's not behaving as I would expect.

I would expect that if I hold the device in a single location, measure the magnetic field, and then rotate the device 90° that the new magnetic field reading would be orthogonal to the first. Or, if rotated 180° that the two vectors would be equal in magnitude, but opposite in direction. I'd also expect that the strength of the field would be almost the same in a single position regardless of the device's orientation.

But none of these are behaving like expected. Vectors that should be orthogonal are turning out to have a dot product above 0.8 (each vector normalized). Vectors should have a dot product of -1 if I rotated the device 180°, but in my tests I get a dot product of around 0.9 (and not negative).

The magnitude varies greatly too. Some orientations it's 250, and in others it's 45.

The only thing to note is that it is consistent--when I return the device to the same orientation and position, the numbers are roughly the same.

So if the numbers (x, y, and z) aren't the true values of the field along those axis, what are they? Or if it's not a vector space, what is it measuring?

---

#### Update

Here's some example code to play around with:

```
public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager sensorManager;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Log.i("SENSOR", event.getValues());
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Geomagnetic field sensor should be independent of the orientation of the device. It measures the Earth magnetic field strength and thus should only depends on the location and not on the orientation of the device. All your dot products above should be close to one as you dot a normalized vector against itself. The coordinates of the magnetic vector varies only because the magnetic vector are expressed in the device coordinates. Thus when you change the device orientation the coordinates change but the vector remains the same.

Comment: Key word should. I was measuring device coordinates (I believe) so I would expect that rotating the device 90 degrees would produce a vector 90 degrees away from the first. However, that wasn't the case. Also doesn't explain the huge difference in magnitude at different angles.

Comment: What you are trying to do is similar to trying to add a binary representation of a number with a base ten representation which you can't. When adding number the base should be the same. When you rotate the device the magnetic vector does not change. It is the bases that change and thus this same magnetic vector has different coordinates. You cannot apply the dot product because of different bases.

Comment: Ok, if the basis of the magnetic sensor was non-orthogonal in world coordinates, we should see what I'm seeing. How do we find the transformation matrix of basis then?

Comment: You have to register for SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY or SENSER_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and call getRotationMatrix. The resulting rotation matrix is the transformation matrix of basis from the device basis to the world basis.